# Measure height of div1 and make div2 same height with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the height of div1 and make div2 the same height.

I can give div2 a set height with
this:

```
$('#div2').height(1000);
```

However the following does nothing:

```
$('#div2').height(
    $("#div1").height()
);
```

Do I have a syntatical error?

UPDATE the element that im trying to set the height of already has its height set with an inline style that is set earlier on with javascript.

Comment: It looks fine - `console.log($('#div1').height())` and make sure it's returning the expected value.

Comment: My guess is that one contains an image, and the image isn't loaded.

Comment: It should work the way you did it. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/mW37Y/

Comment: Code works fine: http://jsbin.com/azomeb/1/edit

Comment: Any console errors? Is jquery properly loaded? check these two.

Comment: The only error I get is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined (anonymous function)' but this is from measureIt.js:120 which is a separate library that my drupal theme must be using.

Comment: Wrap it in `$(window).load(function(){ /* your code */ })` just to make sure everything is loaded before you calculate stuff